# How do I consolidate my redundant system files?

Tags: macbook-pro, filesystem, macos

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inches, mid-2015) with a 2.8 GHz Intel quad core i7 processor, running OS Catalina 10.15.3. The following may also be relevant to my issue. When initially setting this up a few years ago, I migrated my contents from my old G5 tower. A bit later, I changed the default language from English to Spanish.

I'm in the process of cleaning and re-organizing my files and directories, and I'm noticing a lot of redundancy in my system files, in particular the Applications and Library directories. In some cases, I cannot alter these; in other cases I'm not sure if I should. I want to know if it's advisable to consolidate these and, if so, how.

The root directories of my main disk (with English translation in parentheses) are

- Biblioteca (Library)
- Aplicaciones (Applications)
- Sistema (System)
- Usarios (Users).

There is another Applications directory at Sistema\Aplicaciones
which is a repeat of some of the files in the other directory. I cannot alter this.

In many other locations on my disk, I find duplicate Library directories, sometimes in English, sometimes in Spanish. Sometimes these are subsets of the root directory versions and sometimes they contain a combination of repeats and new things. Other such Library directories exist at:

- Biblioteca\Apple\Library
- Biblioteca\Apple\System\Library
- Sistema\Biblioteca
- Usarios\j0equ1nn\Biblioteca
- Usarios\j0equ1nn\Biblioteca\Containers\com....\Data\Library (There are a couple hundred different paths like this with the "..." a directory filed in various ways, mostly starting com.apple. The contents from one to the next is usually identical.)
- Usarios\j0equ1nn\Biblioteca\Group Containers... (Like the previous item, but there are about 30 of these with the "..." starting wither "com" or "group." Each contains just 1 to 3 directories, mostly identical, mostly empty.)

Comment: Are you doing a fresh install of Catalina meaning you *erase* the drive before installing or are you upgrading your existing installation to Catalina.  I suggest doing a wipe and clean install and it will install only the files it needs.

Comment: I wasn't doing an install of Catalina, but have just been upgrading the existing OS as each update came out. This sounds like a good suggestion. I just need to be careful about backing things up given that they're disorganized.

Comment: I always do a clean install.  I have a list of the software that I use and when I install a new version, I do clean installations of the software, too.  The only thing I migrate over is data.  Time Machine is actually very good at backing up data and settings.

Comment: I have my data backed up on Dropbox already anyway, so I'll give this a shot.